Why is an SSD NVMe appearing as an HDD on my Asus TUF gaming laptop?
I have an Asus TUF FX15 506LU-HN003 i5-10300H 16G 512 SSD GTX 1660Ti 6G 15.6 FHD IPS,black 144Hz that is running Windows 11.
The storage type is NVMe Micron_2210_MTFD.
This is what device manger shows:
Micron_2210_MTFDHBA512QFD
Capacity:   477 GB
Formatted:  477 GB
System disk:    Yes
Page file:  Yes
Type:   HDD

The problem is that device manger reads it as an HDD and the speed for reading/writing is around 100MB/s to 200MB/s.
I tried to use winsat disk -drive c in command prompt and winsat formal commands, but they didn't work.
Here is speed information:
Windows System Assessment Tool
Running: Feature Enumeration ''
Run Time 00:00:00.00
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -ran -read'
Run Time 00:00:00.36
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -seq -read'
Run Time 00:00:03.03
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -seq -write'
Run Time 00:00:09.41
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -flush -seq'
Run Time 00:00:01.20
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -flush -ran'
Run Time 00:00:01.23
Dshow Video Encode Time                      0.00000 s
Dshow Video Decode Time                      0.00000 s
Media Foundation Decode Time                 0.00000 s
Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       241.63 MB/s          8.0
Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   1288.20 MB/s          8.6
Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  71.53 MB/s          6.0
Average Read Time with Sequential Writes     0.925 ms          7.7
Latency: 95th Percentile                     0.641 ms          8.6
Latency: Maximum                             33.872 ms          7.9
Average Read Time with Random Writes         1.183 ms          8.2
Total Run Time 00:00:15.59

I found that SSD connected as USB hard drive. I can't understand what's happening.




NoteebookCheck.net tested the Micron 2210 MTFDHBA512QFD drive. For example, on the AS SSD tests:

4K-64 Write, median: 976 MB/s
4K-64 Read, median: 589 MB/s
4K Write, median: 141.9 MB/s
4K Read, median: 59 MB/s

(That read was slower than write seems odd to me, perhaps an artifact of write buffering.)
PassMark bench tests were more as I would expect:

Sequential Read: 2,168 MBytes/Sec
Sequential Write: 1,725 MBytes/Sec
Random Seek Read-Write (IOPS 32KQD20): 507 MBytes/Sec
Random Seek Read-Write (IOPS 4KQD1): 89 MBytes/Sec

Your tests with Windows System Assessment Tool (WinSAT) don't seem too far out of line with the published results, above.

Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read: 1288.20 MB/s
Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write: 71.53 MB/s

However, if you feel the drive should be faster, determine whether the issue is with the operating system or the machine itself. For example, if you boot from USB to Linux OS (e.g., Ubuntu Live), and measure SSD R/W speed with Linux tools, is the speed as slow as under Windows OS? If so, then the issue might be in the laptop hardware and/or firmware, rather than anything that can be remedied in Windows. However, if it is faster than on Windows, then look to optimize Windows SSD speed.

Your screenshot absolutely does not indicate your SSD is connected as USB, it’s marked as being removable, but that’s a different problem and easily solved. It’s a harmless configuration error

could you mention how ? i think this is the problem .
